# Is it possible to share google oauth credentials between different services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

Lets say you have a web application that accesses (via api) a user's Google Drive files at a set time each week and performs some kind of task on them.

The user will [grant authorization to the web application](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python) via it's website (which is hosted on App Engine). However, the weekly, scheduled queries to Google Drive will be carried out by cloud scheduler.

Is it possible then for Cloud Scheduler to use the same credentials (access and refresh tokens) gotten by the web application in the first instance?

Can the credentials, for example, be stored in a cloud data storage bucket, which is accessible to both the application and cloud scheduler?

Or is there another means of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you want to store user credential in bucket?

Comment: not necessarily, the access and refresh tokens could be stored anywhere. im more interested to know whether it is possible to share credentials between gcp services.

Comment: If you keep the refresh token, it should work. I never tried. I recommend you to use secret manager for this kind of secret, and to be clear with your users: you keep their credentials, the trust is the first feature of your app!

Comment: Storing credentials in a bucket is a complete no. we have secret manager[1](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) for that as per guillaume. Also, the Cloud Scheduler API uses service account credentials as described in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production). check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-oauth-gmail) its for gmail but may be works for google drive API.

Comment: It use scheduler with cloud http functions and get the oauth credentials but need to test it out.(note: this is community docs not google's official, so we do not promote nor guarantee their accuracy). It is important for the drive API to put your app (once it works) through the OAuth process with GCP because you're accessing user data.[2](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)